# How to get higher gravity

Tags: beer, original-gravity, mashing, efficiency

I am using 60kg undermodified 6 row barley for 300 litres, I performed 60 minutes rest at 64°C and 30 minutes rest at 72°C, but I got 12°Plato original gravity (1.048) after boiling.

Please help me to get a higher gravity.

Comment: What do you mean by "12 degree plato"?  To take a specific gravity the liquid should be cooled to 20C.

Comment: And did you measure with a refractometer or a hydrometer?

Comment: In general, the Plato scale is used by wine makers. In the homebrewing community, we generally use the scalar scale. It's just a number that represents the mass of a cubic centimeter of the liquid, 1.060, for instance. This measurement is done with normally either a hydrometer or a refractometer and ALWAYS done at the same temperature. so, what was our OG? At which temperature did you measure it? How did you measure it?

Comment: 12°Plato is equal to 1.048

Comment: I used hydrometer to check

Answer (score 3):

Undermodified 6-row barley by itself doesn't have enough enzymes to give you complete conversion of starches to sugars, so you end up with low gravity. Add some highly modified malt (i.e. one with high diastatic power) to help out the 6-row. Here is an article that may help: https://byo.com/stories/issue/item/3604-brewing-by-ratio

Comment: I haven't well modified malt, that's why i asked

Comment: Well spotted GigaFemto, if barley is the only ingredient, some malt needs to be added to increase diastatic power of the mash.

Comment: If you can't get well-modified malt, you can purchase amylase enzyme and add that to your mash to help it out.

Answer (score 1):

With all additional information posted in the comments, I will try to answer the question.

First, 12°Plato is equal to a SG of 1.048.  However, the gravity was taken at 30°C, so using [this](http://winemakersacademy.com/specific-gravity-temperature-correction-calculator/) calculator we end up with a corrected SG of 1.033.

When mashing using 6 row malt, a 30 minutes protein rest shoud be done between 48°C and 54°C, see [How to brew](http://howtobrew.com/book/section-3/how-the-mash-works/the-protein-rest-and-modification) for more information.  300L is a lot, make sure to mix it all well to even the temperature.

Then you can raise temperature to about 65°C for 60 minutes.

Temperature close to 76°C is only for a mash out (stopping the enzyme activity).

The second thing to watch is the water pH if your source of water is hard, but the mash temperature is most probably your problem.

As mentionned by GigaFemto, I just realised it is barley and not malt, so yes please add some 2-row/6-row malt to increase the diastatic power in the mash.